# Youtube API search not returning a playlist

Tags: api, youtube, youtube-data-api

I am using the Search endpoint of Youtube's API to search for playlists titles from a specific channel. My code was working fine, but suddenly this search feature doesn't work for a specific playlist.
In this case I was using the following query:

> GET
>   https://www.googleapis.com/youtube/v3/search?part=snippet&channelId=UCp9TXGvv2-7JVVdyKEi0A6A&q=shadow+warrior&type=playlist&key={YOUR_API_KEY}

This query is used to look for the playlist called "CohhCarnage Plays Shadow Warrior 2 Pre Release" from the channel CohhCarnage.
The playlist exists (https://www.youtube.com/playlist?list=PLN39y5i_H0FlCLx4nOOdrgNL7K5GHBxOm) and should have been returned by the query, but isn't.
At first I thought it may have been some caching issue, but waiting a day didn't change anything.

Is there any reason why the search API shouldn't return this playlist that I am missing?

Thank you for your help.

kimen

Comment: My guess is that there's something up with the playlist listing or with the channel. I performed a `GET` without adding the `q` parameter (`https://www.googleapis.com/youtube/v3/search?part=snippet&channelId=UCp9TXGvv2-7JVVdyKEi0A6A&type=playlist&key=YOUR_API_KEY`) and didn't see the playlist you mentioned.

Comment: Weirdly enough, the playlist does show up in `https://www.googleapis.com/youtube/v3/playlists?part=snippet&channelId=UCp9TXG%E2%80%8C%E2%80%8Bvv2-7JVVdyKEi0A6A&key=YOUR_API_KEY`
So I do not know what to make of it.

Answer (score 0):

The query now works, and the playlist shows up in the results.
It seems that the search API doesn't use real time data, but is looking up at a cached version of the list. It took too much time to update in my opinion, but at least the results are there.

I may have to look for another way to do the search though, because the update rate is not fast enough for me.